# Does the material of the horn affect the matching of the acoustic impedance of the horn with that of the air?

Tags: acoustics

I am trying to design a directional trumpet, but I think the most important issue is the matching problem with the acoustic impedance of air. Does the impedance of a horn relate only to the dimensions of the horn? Does it have anything to do with the material of the horn?
Doesn't it have anything to do with frequency?

Answer (score 1):

Because horns are so much stiffer and denser than air, their acoustic impedance can be omitted from the dynamics of a horn/driver system because the mismatch is so great. This means that any sound wave striking the walls of the horn may be assumed to be totally reflected without attenuation.

The only way the mechanical impedance of the *horn* can affect the transmission of sound out of it is if the horn itself has a mechanical (vibratory) resonance within the frequency range of the horn's driver. Horns are carefully designed to minimize this, but when it does occur, it is controlled by gluing pads of tar-soaked felt or paper to the outside surfaces of the horn where the vibrations are a maximum.